# Getting the list of all scopes from WSO2 API manager

Tags: wso2-api-manager, scopes, wso2-identity-server

We have written our custom spring API to hit the WSO2 API manager for user authorization and getting the JWT token.Along with this login API,we have also configured all our other spring APIs through the API manager.To hit the /token endpoint before accessing our APIs, we need to give a list of all the scopes which have been created in the API publisher. Right now this list of Scopes has been hard coded from the front end/our UI to hit the APIs.

Is there a way to get this list of scopes directly from WSO2 without hard coding it in the front end while hitting the /token endpoint?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add some code to we have more context.

Comment: curl -k -d "grant_type=password&username=username&password=password&scope=scopeName" -H "Authorization: Basic <Base 64 encoding of Consumer key:consumer secret>"https://localhost:8244/token.   This is the url ,with the respective header and body, we are hitting to get the access token to further hit our subsequent APIs which have been exposed via API manager. How to get the 'scope' field dynamically and not hard code it.